# Spring OAuth2, access ROLE with userInfoUri?

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I'm in the process of building separate resource server and authhorization server. For now i'm using the user-info-uri in resource server to extract the Principal from the authorization server matching the access-token, with config:

```
spring:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:9999/uaa/user
```

In the resource server I have protected endpoints, based on role, as follows:

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/invoices/**").hasRole("END_USER")            
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

When I manually access the user-info-uri, I can see that the the authorities contain:

```
"authority": "ROLE_END_USER"
```

But when I try to access the /invoices resource I get an Access-Denied exception, and in the log I see:

```
OAuth2Authentication@bc5074a8: Principal: my-login; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: remoteAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, tokenType=BearertokenValue=<TOKEN>; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER
```

Authoriteis = "ROLE_USER". Where does that come from, should'nt it be "ROLE_END_USER" at this point also?

I've seen implementations using a shared database for the storage of tokens, is that really necessary for what I want to achive?

Resource Server:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Resource
public class EndUserResourceServiceApplication extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()                
                .antMatchers("/invoices/**").hasRole("END_USER")                
                .anyRequest().authenticated();  
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EndUserResourceServiceApplication.class, args);
    }   
}
```

Auth Server:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableResourceServer
public class ApiAuthServerApplication  extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @Order(-10)
    protected static class LoginConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        @Bean(name = "authenticationManagerBean")
        @Override       
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }

        @Override
        @Autowired
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {                 
            auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());                
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {          
            http            
            .formLogin().permitAll()
            .and()
            .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access")               
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        }

        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private TokenStore tokenStore;

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Autowired
        private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints
            .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager)
            .userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService)                
            .tokenStore(this.tokenStore);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {            

            clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("my-client")    
            .secret("our_s3cret")
            .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")         
            .authorizedGrantTypes("implicit", "password", "refresh_token")
            .redirectUris("http://anywhere")
            .scopes("read")
            .autoApprove(true);
        }

        @Bean
        public TokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new InMemoryTokenStore();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiAuthServerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public Principal user(Principal user) {
        return user;
    }
}
```

Summary:

1. Can I use user-info-uri for validating access-tokens and to use "hasRole"
2. Is it necessary to use shared database for token storage when using separate resource server and authorization server?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a shared token store, which works well at the moment

Comment: How does /user know how to do with the token? Where is that defined?